# list view display data as per priority in view pager

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

i have view pager with 3 fragments . and which have list view  . i have one global `ArreyList<Model>` data 
 Model have

```
public class Model{
 String name,status,value;

 //getter setter for each
  }
```

now i want 1st pos of view pager to display whose status is "B" then 2nd to have "A" and "Z" and 3rd "C"...
 so for that  i have sort it and make 3 arreylist of indiviudal status and pass to list view or is any other good way we can say list view adapter to take this only data once we have global arreylist which have all 3 status ..

Comment: I think to make three different list for every status is good option

Comment: but its optimise way?